# How do I import a model into my console so that I can lookup instances of it from my db?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, model

I'm using PyCharm 2018.2 and Python 3.7.  How do I import a model into my console so that I can lookup instances of it from the db?  I thought this would do it

```
from .models import Article
```

but when I run this on a console, I get the below errors.  I'm not sure what they mean

```
>>> from .models import Article
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"
```

Below is my models.py file ...

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Webpage(models.Model):
   path = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.path

   def create(cls, path):
       Webpage = cls(path=path)
       return Webpage

class Article(models.Model):
    webpage = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.TextField
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    comments = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    front_page = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.path

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, webpage, path, url, votes, comments):
        article = cls(webpage=webpage,path=path,url=url,votes=votes,comments=comments)
        return article
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your app name in your `import` statement:

```
from <name of your app>.models import Article
```

The Django shell runs in your project directory, but `models.py` is in your app directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try the command `python manage.py shell` and then include your model classes.

It's all explained here: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_orm/